# Copying Datatable to SQL Server CE table

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, .net-cf-3.5

I know this question was asked before but I have a little different requirement.

I need to copy data from SQL Server to a local application SQL Server CE file.

I got the table data from main server into a datatable, but I'm not able to efficiently copy that to SQL Server CE table.

I tried an `adapter.update()` but it takes a lot of time if number of rows are large
(took around 3 min for 25k rows)

Inserted each datarow by  calling insert command every time (highly inefficient and probably same as what `adapter.update` is doing)

I tried storing the values into a string and writing an insert command with that string so that I can insert 1000 rows each time I run the command. But it gives an error during parsing at the token ',' near second row value.

Exact error :

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 40,Token in error = , ]

I tried `SqlCeBulkCopy` by erikej, it gives me an error `sqlserverce.dll` reference not found, I double checked I had the reference added and I have SQL Server CE 3.5 sp1 installed on the device.

Exact error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3be235df1c8d2ad3, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies

Any directions on how I should proceed?

Comment: You need 3,5 sp2 properly installed on the device

Comment: Thanks erik , I thought sp1 would be sufficient , Updated to sp2 and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SqlCeBulkCopy provided the 3.5 SP2 cab files are properly installed on the device.